# PHP LDAP Connection

Tags: php, active-directory, server, ldap, radix

I was sent the following LDAP parameters, but am not sure how to establish a connection in PHP. I'm not sure which PHP function to use with each set of parameters. Here are the parameters I was given:

**Server:** ldaps://the_server.com:636

**root DN:** dc=the_info,dc=more_info,dc=com

**User search base:** ou=CompanyUsers

**User search filter:** sAMAccountName={0}

**Group search base:** OU=Security,OU=CompanyGroups

**Group search filter:** cn={0}

**Group membership:** Group membership attribute = memberOf

**Display Name LDAP attribute:** displayname

**Email Address LDAP atribute:** mail

If someone could provide a php script for me that would be great! This is my first time using LDAP and still do not understand all these parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the working code for linux base ldap.
It might be helpful to you.

```
<?php
$username = 'uid=amitkawasthi,ou=CompanyUsers,dc=the_info,dc=more_info,dc=com'; 
$password= 'test'; 
$ds=ldap_connect("the_server.com, 636"); 
echo $ds;
if ($ds) { 
   echo "Binding ..."; 
   $r=ldap_bind($ds, $username, $password); 
   if ($r)
   { 
   $sr=ldap_search($ds,"ou=CompanyUsers,dc=the_info,dc=more_info,dc=com", "uid=amitkawasthi");   
   $entry = ldap_first_entry($ds, $sr); 
   $attrs = array(); 
   $attribute = ldap_first_attribute($ds,$entry,$identifier); 
   while ($attribute) { 
     $attrs[] = $attribute; 
     $attribute=ldap_next_attribute($ds,$entry,$identifier); 
     } 
    echo count($attrs) . " attributes held for this entry:<p>"; 

    $ldapResults = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr); 
//for ($item = 0; $item < $ldapResults['count']; $item++) { 
  // for ($attribute = 0; $attribute < $ldapResults[$item]['count'];                  $attribute++) { 
    //echo  $data = $ldapResults[$item][$attribute]; 
    echo  $data = $ldapResults[0][$attribute]; 
    echo $data.":&nbsp;&nbsp;".$ldapResults[0][$data][0]."<br>";             
   //} 
///echo '<hr />'; 

   echo "OK"; 
   }
   else
   {
   echo "Fail"; 

   }
} 

?>
============================
```